# tomcat8 using stock http - Error reading request, ignored

Tags: tomcat8

stock ubuntu 18 on a digitalocean VM, stock jdk & tomcat, stock server.xml:
gets this every time http client tries to connect (I got other errors trying to use https, so tried reverting back to http and get this now)

system versions:

```
09-May-2018 00:04:50.923 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.30 (Ubuntu)
09-May-2018 00:04:50.927 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Apr 19 2018 11:53:19 UTC
09-May-2018 00:04:50.928 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.30.0
09-May-2018 00:04:50.928 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
09-May-2018 00:04:50.929 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.15.0-20-generic
09-May-2018 00:04:50.929 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
09-May-2018 00:04:50.929 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
09-May-2018 00:04:50.929 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_162-8u162-b12-1-b12
```

heres the errors:

```
09-May-2018 00:05:04.300 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process Error reading request, ignored
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.position(I)Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.init(Http11InputBuffer.java:688)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:672)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

09-May-2018 00:05:04.303 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.limit(I)Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.recycle(Http11InputBuffer.java:280)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.recycle(Http11Processor.java:1709)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.release(AbstractProtocol.java:972)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:940)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

heres the server.xml part (again, generic/stock)

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
<!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
<!--
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"    
           port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
-->
```

google seems to have NOTHING on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be the same problem as this: [Tomcat thowing NoSuchMethodError for Nio2Endpoint.setSocketOptions after start serving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930097/tomcat-thowing-nosuchmethoderror-for-nio2endpoint-setsocketoptions-after-start-s)

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=895866

> This issue happens because
>   tomcat8/8.5.30-1 was built with OpenJDK 9 and can no longer run with
>   OpenJDK 8 due to the use of new java.nio.ByteBuffer methods.If you
>   switch to OpenJDK 9 to run Tomcat the issue should go away. I'll make tomcat8 runnable again with OpenJDK 8 in the next update.

Tomcat 8.5.31 has been [released](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/RELEASE-NOTES.txt)  but hasn't made its way in the [ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/tomcat8) packages.